# zurb-foundation conflicts with fullcalendar

Tags: sass, fullcalendar, zurb-foundation

I have just installed zurb-foundation into my rails project that was already using Fullcalendar. After the install i immediately noticed that most of fullcalendars styling was messed with, some really obvious bugs occuring (shaded areas now only half covering dates, button hover-state is now half filled blue for no reason). Ideally id like my js/scss framework to have no effect on fullcalendars (and other js plugins) styles.

There are a couple of potential solutions;

I could only take in bits of foundations SCSS and javascript so that i avoid the conflicting areas. I can find how to do this for the JS, but the SCSS doesnt seem to work: when i remove *= require foundation it seems to keep the scss there anyway, even when i try deleting the cache.

I could find the culprit areas of foundation and change them, but i dont really know where to start with that, the foundation file structure is weird

Lastly, i could ditch the framework all together and use something less invasive. As i can deal with making my own grid, and my own media queries, i have at least one front end man telling me to ditch frameworks all together, but i am just not much of a designer, so i was after buttons and navbars that look good out of the box. Are there good recommendations for lighter weighted sass frameworks that wont mess with stuff so much? Or should i just roll up my sleeves and style my own buttons from scratch...?

Comment: my eventual solution was to use a less invasive framework - I am now using bourbon and neat, having a much easier time with them. another similar option is purecss